# ¿Qué quiere decir "¡príngate!" en el contexto de la frase "Las tareas son de todos y de todas ¡príngate!"?

Tags: vocabulario, coloquialismos, dialectos

Vi la frase *Las tareas son de todos y de todas ¡príngate!* en una valla publicitaria en Andalucía. Trata de la importancia de que los hombres hagan su parte justa de los quehaceres en casa.

A continuación una imagen de la misma, [extraída de Google Maps](https://www.google.es/maps/@36.6030312,-6.2326499,3a,75y,253.35h,93.24t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sgwdQyqKICQ9nOHKT8ORtTA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=es):

[image: ¡Príngate!]

> Conciliación de la vida laboral y familiar
>   Las tareas son de todos y de todas **¡príngate!**
>   Concejalía de Igualdad

¿Qué quiere decir "príngate" en este contexto?

Comment: @walen da la casualidad de que conozco el cartel que menciona K Man. Lo veo todas y cada una de las veces que voy a El Puerto de Santa María, así que me he permitido añadir una imagen del mismo.

Comment: @Charlie qué gran casualidad! Buenísimo que hayas podido añadir una imagen

Comment: No me acordaba de la frase exacta, así que no encontraba esa foto. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"¡Príngate!" es el imperativo de [**pringar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UCFP31z) que, dado el contexto que indicas, hace referencia a las acepciones:

> 4. tr. Manchar con pringue o con cualquier otra sustancia grasienta o pegajosa. U. t. c. prnl.

pero especialmente (énfasis mío) a la

> 12. intr. coloq. **Trabajar mucho**, o más que otros, especialmente en **trabajos duros y con escasa compensación**.

Es decir, el mensaje viene a ser, dirigido a los varones que habitualmente no realiza tareas domésticas:

> "Haz tu parte de las tareas domésticas, aunque conlleve ensuciarse y sea un trabajo duro con escasa compensación".

Comment: He añadido una imagen del cartel para que tengáis más contexto. Tu respuesta es bastante acertada.

Comment: @walen - Tal vez te gustaría redactar una respuesta suplementaria, o dar una sugerencia de cómo mejorar la respuesta.  // Con lo que dijiste de las campañas electorales, capté la idea de esta frase en inglés: "Step up [to the plate]!" -- ¿entendí bien?

Comment: @walen - Pues cada quien tiene su propio estilo.  Yo escribo muchos posts con el prólogo "respuesta suplementaria" porque me parece correcto lo que ya se escribió pero tengo otra manera de explicarlo que me parece útil para un estudiante del español (por ejemplo).  Si estuviera buscando los puntos haría una respuesta completa. Pero cada quien decide cómo quiere aportar. // Escribiste tu sugerencia así: "yo destacaría en la respuesta".  En mi experiencia en SE la gente suele adoptar las sugerencias con más frecuencia, con algo así: This answer could be strengthened with the addition of ....

Comment: Entonces, no, "Step up" no es.  Quizás *Don't be afraid to get your hands dirty.*  Gracias por explicar las sutilezas.  Nunca había oído ese verbo, *príngate*.

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo: *Pitch in* or even better: Muck in.*  *Don't be afraid to muck in.*

Comment: @walen - okay, that was a satisfying tangential jaunt.  "Get your hands dirty!" would *not* work as a poster slogan; the pros would reject "Don't be afraid to get your hands dirty" because it's too long for a poster.  The winner is ... "Muck in."  But if I were going to make a poster in English to get husbands to get up off their behinds I'd take a different approach -- maybe show a mop and pail prominently with some backdrop suggesting family life, and a slogan like "It takes two to keep a family going!"  Needs work -- I don't have a talent for writing slogans.  But I like "It takes two...."